# HTML5 VIDEO tag not playing audio / muted

Tags: html, audio, video

My HTML5 video starts playing (in Chrome and Safari) without audio and mute button seems disabled. so I'm unable to un-mute. the player has sound in the file, so it plays properly in a player (example vlc).

Check screen below:

```
<video class="media" width="920" height="520" preload="auto" poster="img/posters/poster.jpg">
    <source src="video/desktop/resized/film.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to drag the file into the browser to play it, i.e. without loading it via HTML? It could be the wrong flavour of MP4, which the browers cannot play correctly.

Comment: there was a problem with the encoding. :/

Answer (score 3):

The audio codec is not supported for some video player and currently not supported by other browsers.Try to convert the video with proper audio codec,example **MPEG AAC Audio**.

Answer (score 0):

The audio gets disabled because the browser (Which you might have used for testing like 'Live Preview' or 'Go live') you're playing the video file doesn't support the audio codec.

[Screenshot of audio disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxcID.jpg)

Open the HTML file in a supported browser like Chrome or any new browser, which supports it by default. This is guaranteed to work.

[Screenshot of working audio in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQb3q.jpg)

You may check the 'browser compatibility' section in the MDN docs as in the link below:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#browser_compatibility